# Xamarin iOS - UIImageView inside UIScrollView displaced after orientation change

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I have an issue with an image view I'm adding dynamically to my scrollview. I'm using iOS 8 and Size Classes and Auto Layout. The scrollview has been added via the storyboard and I have also added constraints to match the size of the View.

The challenge is, the dynamically added imageview starts centered, but after an orientation change, it gets displaced within the scrollview.

There are tons of solutions here, and most of them pointed to overriding the **ViewWillLayoutSubviews()** function and then setting the UIImageView's center to the scrollview's there. None of the suggestions have worked for me. Whenever I rotate the device, the imageview gets displaced.

Some suggestions I've tried

[UIScrollView with centered UIImageView, like Photos app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638299/uiscrollview-with-centered-uiimageview-like-photos-app)

[Center UIImageView inside UIScrollView without contentInset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445496/center-uiimageview-inside-uiscrollview-without-contentinset?lq=1)

Here's how I'm adding the UIImageView. This function is called in the ViewDidLoad().

```
public void AddImageInScrollView(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            //Setting up the imageView

            var imageUrl = Items.fetchImages[index]; 

            //Setting up the imageView
            imageView = new UIImageView(); 
       //call method to load the images
            imageView.SetImage(
                url: new NSUrl(imageUrl.AbsoluteUri),
                placeholder: UIImage.FromFile("sample.png"),
                completedBlock: (image, error, type, url) =>
                {
                    imageResizer = new ImageResizer(image);

                    imageResizer.RatioResize(100,100);

                    UIImage resizedImage = imageResizer.ModifiedImage;
                    //when download completes add it to the list
                    Car.images.Add(resizedImage);

                });
            //end method call

            imageView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
            imageView.Center = ScrollViewMain.Center;


            //Adding the imageView to the scrollView as subView
            ScrollViewMain.AddSubview(imageView);

          //ScrollViewMain.ContentSize = imageView.Image.Size;
            ScrollViewMain.ContentSize = new CGSize(ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Width,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Height);
           catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

**The ViewWillLayoutSubviews function**

```
    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews ();

        imageView.Frame = new CGRect(0,0,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Width,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Height);

        CenterScrollViewContents ();
    }
```

**The CenterScrollViewContents function**

```
   public void CenterScrollViewContents()
    {
        try
        {

        var boundsSize = ScrollViewMain.Bounds.Size;

        var contentsFrame = imageView.Frame;

        if (contentsFrame.Size.Width < boundsSize.Width) {

            contentsFrame.X = ((float)boundsSize.Width - (float)contentsFrame.Size.Width) / 2.0f;

        } else {
            contentsFrame.X = 0.0f;
        }

        if (contentsFrame.Size.Height < boundsSize.Height) {

            contentsFrame.Y = ((float)boundsSize.Height - (float)contentsFrame.Size.Height) / 2.0f;

        } else {
            contentsFrame.Y = 0.0f;
        }

        imageView.Frame = contentsFrame;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

A sample screen shot of what it looks like after rotation

[image: Screen shot of displaced image in land scape mode]

Comment: You are not updating the ContentSize of the ScrollView. I'd assume, that this is the problem.

Comment: I am already doing that in the AddImageToScrollView function which is called in the ViewDidLoad().                           //ScrollViewMain.ContentSize = imageView.Image.Size;
  ScrollViewMain.ContentSize = new CGSize(ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Width,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Height);

Comment: Yes but not in the Update `ViewWillLayoutSubviews`. Just try to copy `ScrollViewMain.ContentSize = new CGSize(ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Width,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Height);` to this function.

Comment: Nothing changes. I added it above the other two lines inside that function. The image is still not centered whenever I rotate the device.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Have you got a small example project somewhere?

Comment: Here's a link to a sample project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwof42ToptGsT19TM2JZaVFfWVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To get to this view, click on the drawer then click on Tab A. On the list of of images, when you select a single image, it should load up a similar view.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe did you manage to look at the sample project?

Comment: I wanted to but then I saw, that you already resolved the issue, so I went on with other stuff :)

Comment: I realize now that my solution was a temporary fix. Even with that slight modification, it still gets displaced. This bug is very annoying. Could you kindly look at it, if you don't mind? A second set of eyes might help.

Comment: Ok in a few hours :)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really build it. Do you have a minimal example with just one viewcontroller and without all this binding stuff?

Comment: Give me a minute. Adding a link right now.

Comment: Okay, here's a link to a single view app : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwof42ToptGsMkhHWExXWk4zeHc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code from `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` to `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`. The difference is that [ViewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) is *"Called to notify the view controller that its view is about to layout its subviews."* and [ViewDidLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) is *"Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews."*

The problem is, that `ScrollViewMain.Frame` is

```
{X=0,Y=0,Width=375,Height=667} in ViewWillLayoutSubviews
```

but

```
{X=0,Y=0,Width=667,Height=375} in ViewDidLayoutSubviews
```

The Function looks like

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
    ScrollViewMain.ContentSize = new CGSize(ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Width, ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Height);
    imageView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Width, ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Height);
    CenterScrollViewContents();
}
```

Bonus Protip:

You can use `imageView.Center = ScrollViewMain.Center;` to center views.

And if you have some more time, have a look at Autolayout constraints. They save you Frame calculation pains.

Comment: I moved the code from ViewWillLayoutSubviews to ViewDidLayoutSubviews as you suggested, but there's no change. The ViewDidLayoutSubviews is not being called and the image is still not centered. Sometimes even before rotating the device and also gets displaced after rotation. I'm also using AutoLayout constraints for every other screen. This is the only view where I needed dynamic UIImageViews. I'm downloading the images from a server, so I've noticed that only the very first image gets displaced, before and after rotation because the frame size is 600x600. After swiping, the frame is smaller.

Comment: Your real app or the sample? Have you debgugged it and looked at the frame size? Try `imageView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red` to see if the Frame of the image fits. Are you testing on the simulator or the device? I'll have a look if I have changed something else, this afternoon.

Comment: It works!!..It works. I just had to clean the project and build it again. ViewDidLayoutSubviews is now being called. Thanks  a lot. You saved my life :-) I've accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using a simple solution. I realized that while initializing the imageView, I didn't pass the frame size into it's constructor. There are multiple ways to do it, but for my case, after a screen rotation,it seems the size was not being updated.

Before:

```
        imageView = new UIImageView(); 
        imageView.Frame = new CGRect(0,0,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Width,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Height);
```

Solution:

```
        var frame = new CGRect(0,0,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Width,ScrollViewMain.Frame.Size.Height);
   //Setting up the imageView
        imageView = new UIImageView(frame);
```

The image inside the scrollView now is always centered even after orientation changes.