# Why is UIScrollView's contentSize adjusted when zooming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

With the code below, I see a red square appear which I can scroll around (because scrollview's content is 4x screen).

But once I start zooming out (scale < 1.0), the scrollview's `contentSize` immediately jumps to `scale` times the iPad's screen size. For example:

```
0.985783 757.081249 1009.441665
```

After which I cannot move the square around anymore. I can only move the square when `scale` get's above 1.0; in which case the scroll indicators show that the `contentSize` is still `scale` times screen size.

Another effect is that when zooming out below 1.0, the red square moves toward the top-left corner normally by zooming out. However, after I release the screen (without any further zooming), it moves even further to the corner. EDIT: This must be the rubber banding of the scrollview.

(The square itself does scale as expected.)

What I am missing here? Here's my view controller code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView                  = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.scrollView.contentSize      = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 2, self.view.bounds.size.height * 2);
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5f alpha:1.0f];
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1f;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0f;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds    = YES;
    self.scrollView.delegate         = self;

    self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.scrollView.bounds];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 400, 100, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:view];
}

#pragma UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.contentView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
                       withView:(UIView*)view
                        atScale:(double)scale
{
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f", scale, self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your first part, but the moving-to-top-left is normal behavior for scroll views: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316451/center-content-of-uiscrollview-when-smaller

Comment: @JesseRusak Great post, thanks. Having a look at it made me realise that this additional move to the corner was caused by rubber banding of scrollview (see edit).